# Using Vlookup for multiple occurences and find the non-empty values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]

I have a table that looks like this and I want to use something like VLOOKUP to find the 2nd column value that's non-empty.

An example would be:

VLOOKUP("Kiwi", Range A:B, 2, 0) should return Green

**VLOOKUP("Apple", Range A:B, 2, 0) should return Red**

**VLOOKUP("Pineapple", Range A:B, 2, 0) should return Yellow**

Note that the first occurence of Pineapple is empty, but it still should return Yellow. and I don't have to use VLOOKUP and I am open to other methods too.

I would appreiate help.

Thank you.

Comment: So where're your vba efforts? Just to understand your knowledge level at least.

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak This is what I tried but I don't think I can just compare the range with the string variable?

Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(2, 1 / Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A") = Fruitname), Worksheets("Data").Range("B:B"))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an `INDEX/MATCH` array formula:

[image: INDEX MATCH array formula for multiple criteria over several columns]

The formula is:

```
{=INDEX(B1:B7;MATCH(1;(A1:A7=E1)*(B1:B7<>"");0))}
```

Be aware that this is an array formula, you need to enter it with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**.

This formula will check if column A is "Pineapple" and column B is not a blank. You will get an (imaginary) array that looks like this:

[image: Imaginary arrays]

The values in both arrays are multiplied and only for the last two rows, the result will be `1`. `MATCH` looks up the `1` in this array (only the first occurrence!) and delivers the row number for "Yellow" to the `INDEX` function. `INDEX` then picks up the value in row 6 - which is "Yellow".

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Here is a little trick to enter it normally: `=INDEX(B1:B7;MATCH(1;INDEX((A1:A7=E1)*(B1:B7<>""););0))`. Upvoted for a well explained answer =)

Answer (score 0):

MATCH will give you offset, so you can use OFFSET function.

*IFNA is there to display empty instead of #N/A*

```
=IFNA(OFFSET(B1;MATCH(1;(A1:A7=E1)*(B1:B7<>"");0)-1;0);"")
```